# Does App Engine's Quota Take DST Into Effect?

Tags: google-app-engine, timezone, dst

[According to Google](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#How_Resources_are_Replenished), App Engine replenishes its quota at midnight, Pacific time. It's pretty important to me that I sync some of the datetimes in my app up to that quota timeframe (a day in my app needs to equal a day in the quota), but I can't seem to find out whether the Quota observes DST or not, which kind of matters when implementing a solution. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, DST is taken into account.